# Number of equivalence classes in regular languages as a function of DFA size

Tags: co.combinatorics, fl.formal-languages, automata-theory, regular-language

This question is related to a [recent
question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/7913/what-is-the-number-of-languages-accepted-by-a-dfa-of-size-n)
by [Janoma](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/5396/janoma).

### Background

In constraint programming, a **regular** global constraint $c$ over a
domain $D$ is a pair $(s, M)$ with $s$ a tuple of variables (the
scope) and $M$ a DFA over the domain $D$. An assignment $\theta$ to
$s$ satisfies $c$ if $M$ accepts the string
$\theta(s_1)\theta(s_2)\ldots\theta(s_n)$.

Below, assume that the domain $D$ is fixed. Define an equivalence
relation $\sim$ over the set of strings $T = D^{|s|}$ such that $a
\sim b$ if for every DFA $M$ either $a, b \in L(M)$ or $a, b \not\in
L(M)$. Intuitively, two strings are equivalent iff no DFA can
distinguish them. If that is true, then they also satisfy the same
**regular** constraints.

If we do not restrict the DFAs in any way, then the set of equivalence
classes $T/{\sim}$ is just $T$ itself. I am interested in the number of
equivalence classes wrt. $\sim$ as a function of the number of states $n$
that we allow for the DFA. Clearly, if $n = |D|^{|s|}$ (ignore
constants) then $|T/{\sim}| = |T|$. (Of course, $n$ here will itself be a
function of $|s|$.)

### Questions

1. What is the smallest $n$ for which $|T/{\sim}| = |T|$?
2. What happens below that? In particular,

   - is there an $n$ such that $|T/{\sim}| = O(|s|^{|D|})$?
   - is there an $n$ such that $|T/{\sim}| = O(|s| \times |D|)$?

My motivation for this question is that having a polynomial
($|s|^{|D|}$) number of equivalence classes like this gave me a
tractable case of constraint problems with cardinality constraints. I
am now trying to see if something along these lines can be done for
the regular constraint.

**Edit**: Note also [this answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/7913/what-is-the-number-of-languages-accepted-by-a-dfa-of-size-n/7922#7922) by [Hermann Gruber](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/2367/hermann-gruber) to the question referenced at the top. The bounds in the paper the answer links should yield a $k$ such that the answer to question 1 must be $\geq k$, but it is not obvious to me.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to Question 1,

> What is the smallest $n$ for which $|T/{\sim}|=|T|$?

We have $$n=\max_{|w|=|x|=s,\\ w\ne x}\mathrm{sep}(w,x)$$
where $\mathrm{sep}(w,x)$ is the smallest number of states in any DFA that accepts one of $w$ and $x$, but not the other.
The best known upper bound on $n$ is then (see [some slides by Jeffrey Shallit](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~shallit/Talks/sep2.pdf))

> $n=O(s^{2/5}(\log s)^{3/5})$.

which was obtained in

*Robson, J. M.*, [**Separating strings with small automata**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0020-0190(89)90215-9), Inf. Process. Lett. 30, No. 4, 209-214 (1989). [ZBL0666.68051](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0666.68051).